# Given two arrays of numbers

Tags: algorithm

Given two arrays of numbers a[1],...,a[n] and b[1],...,b[n] where each number is 0 or 1, Write an algorithm that takes Θ(n) time and space to find the largest span (i,j) such that a[i]+a[i+1]+....a[j]=b[i]+b[i+1]+.....b[j] or report that there is not such span.

I came across this Program:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define size 100 //assume n is less than 100
    int main()
    {
    int n, a[size], b[size]; 
    int start[2*size], end[2*size];
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, i;
    int diff[size];
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter b[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]) sum1++;
        if(b[i]) sum2++;
        diff[i] = sum1 - sum2;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
        start[i] = -1;
    start[n] = end[n] = 0;  //initially sum is 0 at the beginning of array and the first n-1 elements of start and end are used if sum of A till ith element is less than sum of B till ith element
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(start[diff[i] + n] == -1)
            start[diff[i] + n] = i;
        end[diff[i] + n] = i;
    }
    int max = -1;
    int savei = -1; //savei is for storing the sum having the largest span

    for(i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        if(start[i] > -1 && (end[i] - start[i] > max))
        {
            max = end[i] - start[i];
            savei = i;
        }

    }
    if(savei >= 0)
    {
        printf("The largest span is from %d to %d\n", start[savei]+(savei != n), end[savei]);
    //when sum zero is having the largest span, span starts from first element itself. Else, the span starts from the next element from which the span does not change
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No span\n");
    }
}
```

I could not understand how this algorithm works.  Please help me understand this.

I understand that the program calculates the difference between the sum of a and sum of b so far. We initialize Start to -1 and set start[n] and end[n] to 0. After this I'm don't have a clue why the program does what it does.

Comment: What have you got so far? You need to provide some effort of work towards a solution yourself.

Comment: I understand that the program calculates the difference between the sum of a and sum of b so far. We initialize Start to -1 and set start[n] and end[n] to 0. After this I'm don't have a clue why the program does what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea.

Define `pre_a[i] = a[0]+a[1]+...+a[i]` and `pre_b[i] = b[0]+b[1]+...+b[i]`.

When do we have that `a[i]+a[i+1]+...+a[j] = b[i]+b[i+1]+...+b[j]`? 
We have this when `pre_a[j]-pre_a[i-1]=pre_b[j]-pre_b[i-1]` or equivalently `pre_a[j]-pre_b[j]=pre_a[i-1]-pre_b[i-1]`.

If we now define `diff[i] = pre_a[i]-pre_b[i]` we can see that our problem is actually finding `j>i` such that `diff[j] == diff[i-1]` and `j-i` is maximal. Since `diff[i]` ranges over `[-n,n]` then for each `k` in `[-n,n]` we can calculate which is the maximal `j` such that `diff[j]=k` and which is the minimal `j` such that `diff[i]=k` (stored in `end` and `start` respectively). All that is left to do is to find the maximal `end[k]-start[k]` for `-n<=k<=n`.